# AppleScript - alert window issue when using launch command

Tags: dialog, applescript

I have downloaded an application from internet(from Chrome browser) named "a.app", and there will be an alert window shown if I launch it, see the bellow figure.
[image]

The problem is, when I double click on a.app, the alert dialog will show up immediately, but if using the following AppleScript, the dialog will wait up to 20 seconds before it appears.

```
tell application "a.app" to launch
```

20 seconds go beyond my patience, so I wonder if it is possible for AppleScript to perform just as manually double click on a.app, that is, how to show up the alert dialog the moment I launch a.app by way of AppleScript.

Any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you really re-downloading the .app all the time? Because else your Mac should actually remember your choice to allow the .app  to run...

Comment: … unless of course you´ve decided to run the .app directly from a  .dmg that has been mounted read-only (the way most .app´s are distributed); then you would need to remove the quarantine on this .dmg before launching the .app with `do shell script "xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/the/dmg"`

Comment: @Asmus: Indeed, a.app is a bundle file not a .dmg file. And, because I am doing software tests, there are many new builds every day, I need to re-download one if a new build comes. Besides, I want to do all this in an automatic way, so I need launch it using AppleScript, but comes the issue I have asked.

Comment: @user435657: well, when you download the .app it surely is compressed in any way (like .zip or .dmg)? Even if not, I guess the `xattr -r` part I posted above should also work on `path/to/a.app` to remove the quarantine on downloaded files. So run this beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two options:**

Remove the quarantine after downloading the App (like Asmus mentioned):

```
do shell script "xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/the/dmg"
```

Permanently disable the warning by running this AppleScript line once.

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO"
```